# How to sort javascript array following a predetermined hierarchy

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Let's say I have this hierarchy:

```
0 King
1 Queen
2 Tower
3 Bishop
4 Knight
5 Pawn
```

and an array with this elements:

```
array = [Tower, Pawn, Bishop, Queen]
```

How can I sort it to become like this following the hierarchy?

```
array = [Queen, Tower, Bishop, Pawn]
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: You can use `Array.sort(sortingFunction)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an object that defines the hierarchies:

```
const hierarchyMap = {
  King: 0,
  Queen: 1,
  Tower: 2,
  Bishop: 3,
  Knight: 4,
  Pawn: 5,
}
```

then sort the array based on the hierarchy value:

```
array.sort((first, second) => hierarchyMap[first] - hierarchyMap[second]);
```

or vice versa:

```
array.sort((first, second) => hierarchyMap[second] - hierarchyMap[first]);
```

```js
const hierarchyMap = {
  King: 0,
  Queen: 1,
  Tower: 2,
  Bishop: 3,
  Knight: 4,
  Pawn: 5,
}


let array = ["Tower", "Pawn", "Bishop", "Queen"];

let sorted = array.sort((first, second) => hierarchyMap[first] - hierarchyMap[second]);

console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

You sort it. Then you map over.

I would suggest to use array with objects. Maybe you want to add more properties later in the future so you can easy add more properties to it.

```js
let data = [
  {pos:5, role:"King"},
  {pos:6, role:"Queen"},
  {pos:4, role:"Tower"},
  {pos:2, role:"Bishop"},
  {pos:3, role:"Knight"},
  {pos:1, role:"Pawn"}
]

let result = data.sort((a,b) => a.pos - b.pos)
             .map(({role}) => role);

console.log(result);
```